# Sorting a TableView alphabetically in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I have searched Stack Overflow well and truly with a variety of different options offered but none I can seem to get working.

I have an app which has a glossary of terms for NFL (e.g. offence/defence) etc. It comes from a JSON API and is stored locally. I would like to sort the data programmatically, so the terms are all listed in their respective sections ("A", "B", "C" etc.) alphabetically.

**View Controller:**

```
import UIKit

class GlossaryVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private let glossaryCellId = "GlossaryCell"

    var glossarys = [Offence]()
    var filteredGlossarys = [Offence]()
    private var subCategorySet: Set<String> = []
    private var glossarysDictionary: [String: [Offence]] = [:]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var noResultsView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        filteredGlossarys = glossarys

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        searchBar.delegate = self

        noResultsView.isHidden = true

        hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        DataProvider.getData(with: .GLOSSARY_DATA_URL) { (letters) in

            self.glossarys = letters.flatMap { $0.offences }
            self.filteredGlossarys = self.glossarys
            self.groupGlossarys()

        }

    }

    func groupGlossarys() {
        glossarysDictionary.removeAll()
        subCategorySet.removeAll()
        for glossary in filteredGlossarys {
            subCategorySet.insert(glossary.glossaryLetter!)
        }

        for subCategory in subCategorySet {
            glossarysDictionary[subCategory] = []
        }

        for glossary in filteredGlossarys {
            var list = glossarysDictionary[glossary.glossaryLetter!]
            list?.append(glossary)

            glossarysDictionary[glossary.glossaryLetter!] = list
        }
        checkAndShowTableView()
    }

    func checkAndShowTableView() {
        if subCategorySet.count > 0 {
            tableView.isHidden = false
            noResultsView.isHidden = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            tableView.isHidden = true
            noResultsView.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

        let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return subCategorySet.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let subCategoryList = Array(subCategorySet)
        return subCategoryList[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let subCategoryList = Array(subCategorySet)
        let glossaryList = glossarysDictionary[subCategoryList[section]]
        return glossaryList!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let glossaryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: glossaryCellId, for: indexPath) as? GlossaryCell else {
            fatalError("Unable to dequeue contact cell")
        }

        let subCategoryList = Array(subCategorySet)
        let glossaryList = glossarysDictionary[subCategoryList[indexPath.section]]
        glossaryCell.configure(glossary:(glossaryList?[indexPath.row])!)
        return glossaryCell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let viewGlossaryDetailsVC = segue.destination as? GlossaryDetailsVC,
            let section = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.section, let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
            let subCategoryList = Array(subCategorySet)
            let glossaryList = glossarysDictionary[subCategoryList[section]]
            let glossarys = glossaryList?[row]
            viewGlossaryDetailsVC.glossarys = glossarys
        }
    }

}


extension GlossaryVC: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            filteredGlossarys = glossarys.filter({ (glossary) -> Bool in
                let glossaryTitleRange = glossary.glossaryTitle?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)
                let glossaryDescriptionRange = glossary.glossaryDescription?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)
                let glossaryKeywordsRange = glossary.glossaryKeywords?.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)
                return glossaryTitleRange != nil || glossaryDescriptionRange != nil || glossaryKeywordsRange != nil
            })
        } else {
            filteredGlossarys = glossarys
        }
        groupGlossarys()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I have so far tried the `sorted(by: {})` method on the `let subCategoryList = Array(subCategorySet)` in the `titleForHeaderInSection` which does arrange the section headers alphabetically but the data doesn't change. So you end up having words beginning with "H" in the "A" subcategory.

Data is grouped based on a "letter" key in the database, e.g., so all "A" are grouped together, etc.

Any help would be appreciated, all I want to do is sort it alphabetically and I feel a little out of my depth.

Comment: I would use this model instead for you datasource: `let datasource: [(String, [Offence])] = glossarysDictionary.compactMap { ($0.key, $0.value.sorted(by: { $0.valueForSorting < $1.valueForSorting }))}`, it'd be much easier to keep a sort (in the key order, and inside the values). numberOfSections would be `datasource.count`, numberofRowInSection would be `datasource[section].1.count` if I understood correclty your tableView.

Comment: Hi Larme, thanks for your comment. So you mean change the `glossarys` var to this instead? Or declare this as a new constant?

Comment: If I understood correctly your architecture: https://pastebin.com/yBFfrZ4p